# Is TransferManager reusable after upload?

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I'm using TransferManager to upload a file to my **s3 bucket**. While the documentation says to reuse one instance wherever possible, it also says that shutdown should be called once the transfer is complete.

Relevant portion of the docs:

> TransferManager is responsible for managing resources such as
>   connections and threads; share a single instance of TransferManager
>   whenever possible. TransferManager, like all the client classes in the
>   AWS SDK for Java, is thread safe. Call TransferManager.shutdownNow()
>   to release the resources once the transfer is complete.

Is this to be taken literally, or can we reuse the object and call shutdown when the application is closed?

A bit of background: We were earlier using the same s3 client to create one TransactionManager per upload, but we started getting `AbortedException` thrown on some of the uploads.

Comment: Someone asked the same question [on the AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=764331&tstart=0) and didn't get an answer either.

Comment: I asked this on their chat and was told that it is indeed reusable, but I lost that conversation and don't want to post an answer here without a citation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here: We've reused the transfer manager in testing and production without any issues.

AWS SDK related queries are answered on this chat: https://gitter.im/aws/aws-sdk-java

Searching chat logs with "aws client reusable" should point to the relevant comment by someone on the team.

Transcript of the relevant comments in the chat linked above:

> **soutchay Feb 13 2018 17:08** -  Hi everyone, we have a Spring Boot Java
>   application using aws sdk to upload objects to S3. We have a
>   TransferManager bean and are using it to perform an upload and a
>   waitForUploadResult. The documentation on the TransferManager says to
>   call shutdownNow()after waitForUploadResult completes.
>
> **AdityaVivek Mar 06 2018 11:08** - Hi everyone, I have the same doubt as
>   @soutchay , can TransferManager be reused after upload or does it have
>   to be shutdown immediately?
>
> **jaramd Mar 06 2018 04:17** - Hi Aditya, you can reuse the
>   TransferManager object, which is thread safe actually. It has a
>   executor pool with control number of threads. So you cannot span more
>   that thread pool size.